# VS code: Pressing tab key for auto-completion would exit terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VS code terminal, pressing tab key for auto-completion would exit the terminal and select other components of VS code. How can I stop it? I was testing different shortcuts. I must have accidentally done something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the answer here. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_tab-trapping

Click **Tab move focus** in the center of the bottom bar.